# My Workspace account's profile picture not shown to Gmail recipients

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, profile-picture, google-account-profile

My Google Workspace account profile image isn't displaying to Gmail recipients.

1. I followed the instructions from [Control what others see about you across Google services](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6304920) for my Workspace account.
2. In [About Me](https://myaccount.google.com/profile), under **Basic info > Profile picture**, I confirmed the visibility is correctly set to **Anyone** [image: Visible to anyone].
3. When I send an email from that account to my personal Gmail address, I still don't see the profile picture, instead my first initial in a solid-colored circle is displayed.

What should I do to have my Workspace account's profile image displayed to Gmail recipients?

Comment: In [About Me](https://myaccount.google.com/profile), under **Basic info > Profile picture** if you click the chevron **`>`** (right of the **Anyone** icon) what image is shown & does it include anything like **"Your profile picture is managed by your organization"**?  **Note:** Link you provided to the article does not use the default account but a secondary account (`?authuser=2`), not sure if that is a factor in your problem. **Important:** You didn't actually share what changes you did or didn't make to your profile when you *"followed the instructions"* in the article.